# If I install a clean copy of Windows 7, will it remove Bit Locker?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have an old Laptop I had a very long time ago.

When I turn on the Laptop, I am taken to the Bit Locker Encryption key.  There is no way, that I am aware of, to by pass this.  I do not want to data on the hard drive and would want to reset the hard drive to factory settings.

If I purchased Windows 7 and inserted the USB into the Laptop, would it 'ignore' the Bit Locker screen and take me straight to the Windows installation page?  Upon installation, reset the hard drive back to factory settings and thus remove the Bit Locker and allow the Laptop to be used again?

Comment: The bitlocker key is only necessary to access the encrypted data currently on the computer. Installing a new OS does not require entry of a Bitlocker key as it does not care about data currently on the drive. Do you know if your computer has a TPM or what method was supposed to be used for regular access?

Comment: If i recall correctly, it was just a standard login page in Windows.  The model is a Dell Latitude 6410.  Not sure if that helps.  The Bit Locker screen prevents me accessing Windows.  Just worried if I purchase a new Windows Key, I won't be able to install it due to the Bit Locker screen preventing me from accessing windows etc.

Comment: Be aware that only Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise supported BitLocker.  You will have to format the entire HDD in order to install Windows 7 on a fully encrypted disk.  If you want to enable BitLocker it will require one of those two versions of Windows 7.  **If the machine came with Windows 7 it isn't necessary to purchase another license.**

Comment: How can I fully format the HDD?  I would like to completely remove the Bit Locker and install a fresh install of Windows 7.  I was under the impression that I would need to reinstall a fresh install of Windows 7 in order to format the HDD?

Comment: Craig, you should just stick an OS install disk in and boot to it. Formatting the drive is part of the standard install process, if you choose clean install. The Bitlocker prompt you're getting is only a function of the currently installed OS and should NOT come up as you attempt to boot to another OS or install. I think that you're assuming things may be more difficult than they actually are.

Comment: @music2myear:  Thanks for your time with this.  Are you saying I could purchase and download a Windows 7 OS/Keys, from another computer.  Save the OS to a USB and stick this USB into the Laptop.  Upon doing this, it would boot from the USB and offer to format the HDD and perform a clean install of Windows 7 ... Thus bypassing and eventually removing the Bit Locker?

Comment: Skip purchasing a new license. Look on your computer case to find the OEM key, download the media from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 and put it on the USB using this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool and boot to it.

Comment: Thanks for those resources.  I tried that previously but Microsoft did not recognise the Key since it was a preinstalled version and Dell are charging more than the purchase of a new Product Key, to release the relevant disk etc that I would need.

Comment: Have you tried using the Recovery Partition? On Dell computers this is usually CTRL-F11 during boot. Bitlocker is done per-partition, and so is not likely protecting a recovery partition.

Comment: Also, not recognizing the key means you used the wrong version of Windows 7. You can use an OEM key to activate the CORRECT version of Windows 7 even if you use a Retail disk. This is the MS answer on the subject: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-an-oem-licence-key-be-used-to-activate-a/495b4da1-c1b7-4d93-82a9-8c8601bbaf32

Comment: I receive a 'Configuration Error' when I select CTRL & F11 during Boot.  I followed this resource https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln147555/how-to-restore-the-dell-factory-image-with-dell-backup-and-recovery?lang=en But Bit Locker prevents access to the Advanced BIOS when selecting F8.

Comment: How could I use the OEM key?  I am using the Product Key detailed on the Laptop itself.  The Windows 7 was preinstalled.

Comment: Its f11 not ctrl+F11